# How to map a specific multi-site blog to a folder?

Tags: multisite

I have a multi-site set up in a sub folder called sites, like:

```
domain/sites/blog1
domain/sites/blog2
```

I would like a specific blog called `mag` to be accessible at `domain/mag` without revealing the real structure.

Can it be done with URL rewrites?

Answer (score 1):

in the domain/ .htaccess file, add this line at the beginning.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^mag/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?$ /sites/mag/$2 [L]
```